# How to alter smart cache capability in intel cpus?

Tags: c, c++11, assembly, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache

Is there a programming approach to disable and enable smart cache capability in an intel cpu through c or c++ or maybe assembly code. i would like to measure algorithm performance with and without smart cache!is there such option availables or not?. I search alot but did not find anything useful. my cpu is intel 6700hq.

Comment: The "Smart Cache" feature isn't as smart as it sounds. It just means that the L3 cache is shared between cores, instead each core having their own L3 cache, like with the L2 and L1 caches. In some ways it's a simpler design than having dedicated L3 caches for each core.

Answer (score 1):

Smart cache is a architectural feature, and relies on a certain hardware structure to be present (in detail, the L2/L3 caches of individual cores to not be separated, as well as certain optimizations in data prefetch logic etc.). As such, it is highly unlikely that this feature can be disabled (although I was unable to find any reference on this).

Comment: It is possible that there is a chicken bit for this feature, but I have no idea where to look for such a thing.

Comment: @fuz As Ben Steffan suggested it would require significant of amount of hardware to partition the L3 cache into separate dedicated caches for each core. In order to "disable" the feature there would have a fair bit of the die area of the chip dedicated to something that would only hurt performance if used.